# MySQL query in PHP gives obvious wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using PHP and PHPMyAdmin to create a small profile site.
I'm giving members an ID number, based on which is the biggest number currently in the database, +1

I did 25 tests before I got the PHP script where I wanted it to be.

I then deleted those 25 entries using PHPMyAdmin.

But now, when my PHP code does this:

```
function getLatestID() {
    $query = "SELECT max(member_id) FROM members";
    $result = @mysql_query($query) or showError("unable to query database for user information");
    if (!($record = mysql_fetch_array($result))) return null;
    return $record[0];
}
```

I get the wrong number.

Test scenario: the database table holds 3 entries, with ID's 1, 2 and 3.

I start a debugging session and put a breakpoint on the return `$record[0]`.
I check its contents and instead of 3, which is the biggest number, it's 28.

As in 25+3=28, the 25 entries that I allready deleted...

Does anybody know what's causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably because you have auto_increment set and the query is returning the highest id. When you deleted the other records, you probably didn't reset the auto increment count.

Comment: For future, if you didn't already figure this out, you can reset it by going to the Operations tab for any given table.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using `auto_increment` in MySQL then deleting records won't decrease the next value.

You can empty a table with `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable` - this will reset the value.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Too bad that the truncate command deletes all values. I'm lucky to have only 3 entries to replace. Imagine thousands of entries. Now I understand why people don't usually delete entries from their tables.

Comment: @Vordreller: Nonsense; deleting entries from tables is fine. Expecting the AUTO_INCREMENT ID to miraculously recalculate itself is not, and relying on this would in fact indicate a broken design. It's "AUTO_INCREMENT", not "AUTO_MAX".

Answer (score 3):

You can also change value that auto-increment thinks is the next value to allocate:

```
ALTER TABLE members AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
```

Note that if you put in a value that is less than the current max value in the auto-increment column, it'll change the value to that MAX+1.  To see what the current next value is set to, do this:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE members;
```

At the end of the table definition, it'll show "`AUTO_INCREMENT = 26`" or whatever it's current value is.